# Sub level in json using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Hi Im using php (laravel) and working on foreach loops, im loading my data from a database.
I need my json data to appear with sub elements not in a linear format. Thank you.

My Code

```
 <?php
  $data  = array();
 foreach($colors as $color){

 $data[] = $fruit; 

foreach($fruits as $fruit){
    $get[][] = $fruit;

   }
 }
?>
```

This is the json result:

```
0: Red
1: Apple
2. Strawberry
3: Green
4: Kiwi
5: Guava
```

What I need is for the JSON to appear like this

```
0: Red
  0: Apple
  1. Strawberry
1: Green
  0: Kiwi
  1: Guava
  2: Grapes
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear and can't work, and I suppose the expressed concept is only for example.

The closest thing that I have deduced can be:

```
<?php
 
  $colors = ['Red', 'Green'];
  $fruits = ['Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Guava'];
  
  $data  = [];

  foreach($colors as $color) {

     $data[$color] = $fruits;
     // that is equal to:
     //   $data[$color] = [];
     //   foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
     //       $data[$color][] = $fruit;
     //   }
 }

 print_r ($data);
```

But as I said above, you can see that it is not possible to predict which sub-elements (fruits) will be placed under the first level (colors) and therefore they are all present. Also because if this were possible, you would have the source data already grouped.